# Insert mode in all windows in VI

Tags: vim

Suppose I am using `vim` with two or more files opened in split-screen mode. The open files are very similar, and I want to perform a few identical changes to all files.

I already know of

```
:windo set scrollbind
```

to have the windows scroll in the same way.

My question is the following: is there a method to enter insert mode in all windows. Or, if not, to copy all latest actions to a different window. The result should be that some edit is the same in all open files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can record your editing commands in a **macro** (e.g. register Q via `qq...q`), and then replay that macro in all other windows. If you `:close` the first window that already got the treatment, you can use

```
:windo normal! @q
```

for that.

You need to be careful to only use movements and text objects that are valid in *all* buffers (as Vim will beep and abort a macro replay on error), so this will only work on very similar buffers and a bit of forethought. Best start the macro from a predefined position, e.g. via `gg0` or a `/search`.

The **`:substitute`** command (possibly with the `/c` flag to query on each match) can be a great alternative to normal mode commands, and can be combined / included in a macro.

Comment: Awesome, never took time to understand macros, but know I get why they are useful.